# I have developed a tool which I think can benefit others. Can I publish this to a journal?

Tags: publications, physics, software

I'm a physicist and have written a tool which greatly simplifies my job. Instead of needing to worry about implementation details I can now simply input my data and the software will do all necessary steps in preparation and actual calculation. It is written generically enough that it can be used by anyone who wants to X.  I did not develop a new algorithm, I just developed a library to ease calculations which people would normally have to write a specific program for.

Can I publish this in a journal and which journal would be adequate?